# Do the followers of Ramakrishna Mission consider bible and quran to be authentic and holy?

Tags: other-religions, ramakrishna

What are the views of Ramakrishna Mission on the authenticity of bible and quran? if they do then is it supported by the life and teachings of Ramakrishna?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/90517/discussion-on-question-by-rishx-do-the-followers-of-ramakrishna-mission-consider).

Comment: Swami Vivekananda said that they are as true as any Smriti is true - they are not Sruti, only Smriti. He said that only the Vedas are Sruti.

Comment: Please clarify what exactly you mean by 'authentic'. Do you mean to say it was altered, or that it represents the unadulterated word of 'a' god or saint? Also, please mention if you mean the new or old testament. The bible could stand for many things.

Comment: @user1952500 pls look at my other question https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/33487/does-ramakrishna-mission-consider-itself-a-hindu-organisation                                           I  have posted the statement where RKM stated that consider all other religion books as holy...no line was drawn as such

Comment: @Rishx I understand and have already +1ed the question. I think making it a concrete question will be helpful. By authentic, do you mean RKM thinks that it fits the hinduism model? I mean, other parts of hinduism don't say that other religions are not authentic. They just ignore them.

Comment: @user1952500 As i pointed out in my other question RKM doesn't consider themselves as traditional Hindus as Hindus consider only Vedas as holy where as RKM considers all holy books...Does this include quran and bible and if it does...does these books have same authority in RKM as Vedas have...