# Does Ramakrishna Mission consider itself a Hindu organisation?

Tags: history, ramakrishna

Back in 1980s, Ramakrishna Mission tried to separate legally from Hinduism in order to consider itself as a separate religion (Ramakrishnaism). They claimed various philosophical differences. [Like](https://archive.org/stream/Identity_201605#page/n4/mode/1up):

> Arguing for the “distinct” existence of the Mission, the affidavit says that not all its members are Hindus and, in fact, some of them are Muslims and Christians. The first fact proves that it is non-sectarian, the second that it is universal. This is the pat- tern which the affidavit faithfully observes-when the inclusiveness of the Mission is to be shown, Islam and Christianity are mentioned; when its distinct character is to be shown, Hinduism is mentioned. The Mission is distinct from Hinduism in some respects and similar to Islam and Christianity in others. That makes it unique and universal — that is the line of argument.

Further:

> The affidavit enumerates many points which in the opinion of the Mission distinguishes it from all other religions, “including traditional Hinduism.” It states that a traditional Hindu “believes in the Vedas only, and not in the scriptures of any other religions,” while followers of Ramakrishna cult believe in all holy scriptures.

More of these alleged differences can be found in Ram Swarup's book [Ramakrishna Mission: In Search of a New Identity](https://archive.org/stream/Identity_201605#mode/2up).

My question is, what is the current stance of the Ramakrishna Mission? Do they still consider themselves non-Hindu?

Comment: "Whatever legal brains have done is for lawyers to say" - RK Mission General Secretary, Swami Atmashtananda. The RK Mission's explanation has been all along that it has taken this step to save its schools, and that the court statements are simply part of the necessary legal maneuvers.

Comment: @ChinmaySarupria if they really did it to save their schools from communist govt...then they went the easy way out They should have at least stood up for themselves as well as other Hindus ....like Vivekananda did back in the day...Either way in my question i clearly asked their current stance over this issue.

Comment: As said in my previous comment, those statements were *crafted* to save their schools. They were Hindu, they are Hindu. This question is off topic though.

Comment: This question has to be asked to the authorities of Ramakrishna Mission and not to the members of the forum.

Comment: I guess this site have lot of RKM sympathizers .This question is not off topic..Its related to Hinduism.

Comment: Downvoting a genuine question is a nice way to suppress what you don't want to notice.

Comment: The question is about legal issues and defenses made by lawyers.

Comment: I don't think this is off-scope. The legal matters about whether it should be a separate religion is off-topic but this question asks for the **philosophical differences** mentioned within the case. As per the question, RKM has clearly mentioned philosophical differences that make it non-Hindu and an answer discussing these differences should be in scope and will be enlightening to many hindus.

Comment: @user1952500 I agree.In the legal case,RKM clearly pointed out philosphical differences they had with traditional Hindus.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An American asked the late Swami Swahananda, the former head of the Southern California Ramakrishna Vedanta Center, this question many years ago. I was present. The Swami smiled and said of course the RKM organization is a Hindu organization and these arguments are given by lawyers to stop the Communists from taking over the Ramakrishna Mission schools in West Bengal.

What is the situation now? As soon as the Mamata Banerjee government came to power, the Ramakrishna Mission authorities requested her to grant the RKM a minority status. She has granted their request. The RKM is now considered to be a non-Hindu organization in West Bengal. This is simply a legal maneouvre to protect them from future government interference.

I read about the change of status of RKM in a Bengali newspaper some years ago. I am posting a news report in Times of India that talks about the change of status of RKM after 2011.
https://timesofindia.indiatimes.com/city/kolkata/Administrative-autonomy-for-Ramakrishna-Mission/articleshow/12818087.cms

The RKM followers regard the RKM as a Hindu organization.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/90595/discussion-on-answer-by-pradip-gangopadhyay-does-ramakrishna-mission-consider-it).

Comment: I repeat: please contact the Mission Authorities and rectify your answer.What you have been saying has no basis at all so far the current state govt is concerned

Comment: Are you claiming that the change of status after 2011 (when Mamata govet came) reported by the Times of India paper is wrong?

Comment: Yes, wrong.please consult the Mission Authorities

Comment: The only status that they have been enjoying since the period of the past Left Govt is that they can appoint a monk as honourary Headmaster or Principal in their academic institutions. This has nothing to do with Mamata or Hinduism

Comment: As far as I know the appointment is academic and is honorary. There is no commercial benefit.